# shell variable inside awk without -v option it is working

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I noticed that a shell script variable can be used inside an awk script like this:

```
var="help"
awk 'BEGIN{print "'$var'" }'
```

Can anyone tell me how to change the value of `var` inside awk while retaining the value outside of awk?

Similarly to accessing a variable of shell script inside awk, can we access shell array inside awk? If so, how?

Comment: In this case, you're not using the variable inside the AWK script, you're using the shell variable's *value*.

Comment: I just want to export the variable as a whole inside the shell script and not the value ... Can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible; the only variants you have:

- use command substitution and write output of `awk` to the variable;
- write data to file and then read from the outer shell;
- produce shell output and then execute it with `eval`.

Examples.

Command substitution, one variable:

```
$ export A=10
$ A=$(awk 'END {print 2*ENVIRON["A"]}' < /dev/null)
$ echo $A
20
```

Here you multiple A by two and write the result of multiplication back.

`eval`; two variables:

```
$ A=10
$ B=10
$ eval $(awk 'END {print "A="2*ENVIRON["A"]"; B="2*ENVIRON["B"]}' < /dev/null)
$ echo $A
20
$ echo $B
20
$ awk 'END {print "A="2*ENVIRON["A"]"; B="2*ENVIRON["B"]}' < /dev/null
A=40; B=40
```

Comment: If this is not possible ... Can you please look at the code below. Here the variable A is exported from shell script and then used in awk. Like the same case can I export a variable from awk and use that in shell script                                                $ export A=A
$ awk END {print ENVIRON["A"]} < /dev/null

Comment: I know to do this but I have lot of print statements inside awk and hence I am planning to export each of them as a variable to shell and thats why I am looking for this solution

Comment: @User: `export` exports variables to a child process. Variables can't be exported to a parent process. In this case, the shell is the parent and AWK is the child. My recommendation is that you write the entire script in AWK if there are capabilities it has that you need that are not available in the shell (if the mechanisms that Igor describes are not sufficient). By the way, Igor, +1.

Comment: Thank you for your answers .. @Igor What can eval do .. can I use that to print each variable

Comment: No, you can't print the variables using eval; in opposite: you print variables using `awk` but then import them back to shell using `eval`

Comment: @Igor: Could you please give me an instance .. I am bit confused in understanding this. thanks a lot

Comment: @User: I added example with `eval` already :) do you mean something else?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to see your edited code .. I understood this clearly but how come the value of A and B are getting changed without eval in the second statement . Thank you.

Comment: They are not changes; they are just printed. I just wanted to show what output is produced by `awk`. You need to use `eval` when you want to change the variables in the shell

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.. I really works .. I struggled from morning to do this ... Thank you

Comment: @Igor Just a small question .. In this statement print 2*ENVIRON["A"] ; what is the 2 has to be a variable. Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13762/discussion-between-user-and-igor-chubin)

Answer (score 0):

It uses a file intermediary, but it does work:

```
var="hello world"
cat > /tmp/my_script.awk.$$ <<EOF
BEGIN { print \"$var\" }
EOF
awk /tmp/my_script.awk.$$
rm -f /tmp/my_script.awk.$$
```

This uses the `here document` feature of the shell, Check your shell manual for the rules about interpolation within a here document.

Comment: Could you please relate this with my instance . I am little bit confused in understanding .Also where does the tmp file will be created in main memory or disk